# Filter list in R which has nchar > 1

Tags: r

I have a list of names

```
> x <- c("Test t", "Cuma Nama K", "O", "Test satu dua t")
> name <- strsplit(x, " ")
> name
[[1]]
[1] "Test" "t"   

[[2]]
[1] "Cuma" "Nama" "K"   

[[3]]
[1] "O"

[[4]]
[1] "Test" "satu" "dua"  "t"
```

How can I filter a list so that it can become like this?
I am trying to find out how to filter the list which has nchar > 1

```
> name
[[1]]
[1] "Test"   

[[2]]
[1] "Cuma" "Nama" 

[[4]]
[1] "Test" "satu" "dua"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lapply(name, function(x) x[nchar(x)>1])
```

Results in:

```
[[1]]
[1] "Test"

[[2]]
[1] "Cuma" "Nama"

[[3]]
character(0)

[[4]]
[1] "Test" "satu" "dua"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can loop over the list elements, subset the elements that have `nchar` greater than 1 and use `Filter` to remove the elements that 0 elements

```
 Filter(length,lapply(name, function(x) x[nchar(x) >1 ]))
 #[[1]]
 #[1] "Test"

 #[[2]]
 #[1] "Cuma" "Nama"

 #[[3]]
 #[1] "Test" "satu" "dua"
```

---

If we want to remove the words with one character from the string, we can also do this without splitting

```
setdiff(gsub("(^| ).( |$)", "", x), "")
#[1] "Test"          "Cuma Nama"     "Test satu dua"
```